# jQuery UI Cloned Draggable Element Isn't Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-clone

I'm running into a strange issue with jQuery UI and cloned elements. Even though the jQuery UI events appear to be copied correctly, it seems the events still refer to the original DOM object, and not the cloned one.

This JS fiddle shows the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/XDrC5/

Here's the HTML:

```
<button id="clone">Clone</button>

<div id="source">
  <div id="elem"></div>
</div>

<div id="copy">
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#elem").resizable({
        containment:"parent"
    }).draggable({
        containment:"parent"
    });

  $("#clone").on("click", function() {
    var newHTML = $("#source").clone(true);

      $("#copy").html(newHTML.contents());
  });
});
```

Clicking Clone properly duplicates the orange square in the lower box, but attempting to drag the new square results in the original square moving. Attempting to resize the new square does nothing at all.

This causes bigger problems when attempting to call jQuery UI methods on the cloned elements. For example, calling `.draggable("destroy");` after the clone actually removes draggable from the original element, rendering both new and old immovable.

I'm not sure if there's a way around this, if I'm simply being dense, or if this is an unavoidable bug. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you are creating a new div with the same ID as the previous - use a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think in response to Beetroot-Beetroot the problem might be that by doing `clone(true)` you are copying the events attached to the previous `elem` which means the new elem is stil being told to resize within the `#source` div, try it without `true` and then reattach the resizable event to the elem inside the `#copy` div.

I have updated the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/XDrC5/2/ This seems to fix the draggable issue.

Comment: Beetroot-Beetroot has left the building.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Wezly, but this is just a reduced test case. In the actual production environment, the elements are being added dynamically to the DOM, and aren't being targeted with IDs or classes.

The issue here is more that, unlike other event handlers such as "click", "mouseover", etc., which are either native JS or baked into jQuery core, the jQuery UI widgets don't pass their event association on to the new DOM elements created by clone(true).